# How to compute $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{3^n(n + \frac{1}{2})}{n!}}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

I have to compute the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{3^n(n + \frac{1}{2})}{n!}}$.

$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{3^n(n + \frac{1}{2})}{n!}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{3^n\frac{1}{2}}{n!}} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{3^nn}{n!}} = \frac{e^3}{2} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{3^nn}{n!}},$$ but how to compute the $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{3^nn}{n!}}$?

Answer (score 8):

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{3^nn}{n!} & =0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{3^n}{(n-1)!}\\
& =\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{3^{n+1}}{n!}\\
& =3e^3.\\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{align}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n\cdot 3^n}{n!}&=0+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{3^n}{(n-1)!}\\&=3\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{3^n}{n!}\\&=3\cdot e^3\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

As for integer $n>0, n!=n\cdot(n-1)!,$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{3^nn}{n!}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{3^nn}{n!}}=3\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{3^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}=?$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{3^nn}{n!}}=0+3\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{3^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}}$$

Answer (score 3):

We have
$$
x(e^x)'=xe^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{nx^n}{n!}
$$
Now take $x=3$.